# Не получается подключится к базе данных

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird

Не получается подключится к БД при помощи следующего кода:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    private static final String url =
      "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/bin/LAWYERS_PORTAL.fdb?lc_ctype=WIN1251";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from lawyers-portal");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet);
        }
    }
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Invalid connection string localhost:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/bin/LAWYERS_PORTAL.fdb, reason: Port separator: ':' at beginning or end of: localhost: [SQLState:08001, ISC error code:337248263]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$5.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:537)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:299)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.DbAttachInfo.parseUrlConnectString(DbAttachInfo.java:129)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.DbAttachInfo.parseConnectString(DbAttachInfo.java:78)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:129)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:520)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:117)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:137)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: Invalid connection string localhost:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/bin/LAWYERS_PORTAL.fdb, reason: Port separator: ':' at beginning or end of: localhost:
```

Comment: Если порт не указываете - то уберите : после localhost

Comment: Зачем плодить одинаковые темы?

Comment: Первый раз на stack overflow, понял, больше не буду)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно тебе стоит добавить порт после `localhost` примерно так:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:/Program Files (x86)/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/bin/LAWYERS_PORTAL.fdb?lc_ctype=WIN1251
```

Comment: Возникает новая ошибка: Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server [SQLState:28000, ISC error code:335545064]

Comment: @steed проверь, чтобы версия драйвера совпадала с версией базы.

Comment: Теперь выводится ошибка:unsupported on-disk structure for file found 24578.3, support 12.2 IProvider::attachDatabase failed when loading mapping cache [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544379]